# Road map for a faster spaceship

Tags: interstellar-travel, space-travel

New Horizons, speediest yet, is currently running at about 15 km/sec relative to the sun.  What is the roadmap for future ? How is it possible to reach much faster speeds ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for the Space Exploration Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_travel) discussing various theoretical methods of propulsion. It has some very interesting ideas.

The one that piqued my interest was the Alcubierre drive. For all intents and purposes it is a warp drive - well, as close as science can get to the fictional engine of *The Enterprise* anyway. It has been nicknamed the warp drive, I believe, by NASA scientists.